# fancybox 2 broke my responsive layout

Tags: fancybox, responsive-design

This is my page: http://emresanli.com/sungerbob/

Everything is normal, until opening a fancybox iframe. As you see responsive layout is skidding. What is wrong?

Comment: Delete these properties in your BODY CSS `margin: 0 auto; max-width: 96%; width: 1000px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS "style.css" file change from :

```
body {
    background: #fef752 url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed center center;
    color: #666;
    font: 85%/140% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 1000px;
    max-width: 96%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    cursor: url(images/spongebob.gif), auto;
}
```

to this :

```
body {
    background: #fef752 url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed center center;
    color: #666;
    font: 85%/140% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    cursor: url(images/spongebob.gif), auto;
}
```